# two keyPressEvent in the same class (Pyqt5)

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Hello 
I am using Pyqt5 & QT Designer to create a GUI. and i would like to use two keyPressEvent in one class. one of them to exit from the GUI and the other to hide a button.The problem is that the keyPressEvent overwrite each other so that they can't preform together

Part of the code:

```
....
self.pushButton = MYButton(self.centralwidget)
....

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):    

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.initMe()


        def initMe(self):
            self.pushButton.setToolTip('This is a <u> Button </u>')
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pressed) 
            QToolTip.setFont(QFont('Arial',7))
            self.setToolTip('Das ist ein Fenster!')
            self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)

        def druecken(self): #1
            Sender = self.sender()
            Sender.move(50,50)
            print(Sender.text()+'the Button is already pressed')

        def keyPressEvent(self, e):
            if e.key() == Qt.Key_W:
                self.close()


class MYButton(QPushButton):
      def keyPressEvent(self, e):
          if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
              self.close()
```

So for example i have to press the Escape key first to hide the buttom then i can't press the W Key to close the GUI. But when i do it oppisitly it does not work because MYButton function is still runing and its keyPressEvent is activied. So how i get the both to run together?

Comment: why do not you use an if?

Comment: it means if i press Escape or W then function will be runned. How can i do it without if?

Comment: timer based button.hide()? On the other hand it would be close it and reopen later. But euhm.... why would you like to have such a difficult construction?